# android - get time of the next alarm

Tags: android

Is there a way in Android to get the upcoming alarm time?

Thanks

Clarification: I am talking about the native android Alarm Clock appliction

Comment: As in the alarm clock application, or an Alarm event triggered by an application?

Comment: is the alarm time of the Native Alarm Clock application.

Comment: @Jim Blackler, do you know the answer if it is an Alarm event triggered by an application?  Thanks for your answer in advance :-)

Comment: @monn3t I am answering very late but may be it would help others. You can save the alarm event somewhere persistent like database, sharedpreferences etc

Comment: @FawadKhalil, thanks for your answer.  As you can see this question is from a long time ago.  Things have changed drastically with the OS ever since.  However, I believe your answer is still current.  Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```

Comment: is there any ways to get next alarm time in seconds,rather than a formatted time string?

Comment: Did someone find a way to read the time in seconds to the next alarm ?

Comment: I'd like to see a perfect solution too. A formatted string is simply not sufficient for most cases..

Comment: What about alarm time set by third party apps? Any chances getting that value?

Comment: @Steve, how can I get the time of next alarm from the alarm manager?

Answer (score 20):

Starting with API level 21 the constant `Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED` is deprecated.

Instead, you should use:

```
AlarmManager.getNextAlarmClock()
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#getNextAlarmClock()

Answer (score 1):

Needs to be:

```
String nextAlarm = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```