# Display set alarm in textView

Tags: android, textview, android-alarms

I want to display the current time my alarm is set in a textview but I can't figure out what to do. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600378/android-get-time-of-the-next-alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText edittime;    
edittime=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittime);
```

your alarm code......

```
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(mHour).append(":").append(mMinute);
    String str=sb.toString();
    edittime.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this..

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```