# get the nearest alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So i'm searching a way for getting the nearest alarm set. Looking at go locker i see that this is possible.

Was looking all over the inet, and didn't find anything related to this, every post says that you cant access the alarm list. Looking at the alarm manager class, i can see that there is the class:

```
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo An immutable description of an alarm clock.
```

That has the:

```
getNextAlarmClock() Gets information about the next alarm clock currently scheduled.
```

I tried using the following code: https://code.google.com/p/android-alarm-database/ but no luck

Is it possible to somehow call this method, because its not accessible or any other method ?

EDIT: The class is visible in API 21 or above. My next question is, is there a compatibility library that lets you use something like this in older APIs ?

Comment: You can not do it before API 21. So you need to implement your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are employed by a manufacturer of devices and therefore can be sure about the internals of OS beneath your app, you may try reflection.

Otherwise, I recommend a `TreeSet<Long>` of alarm times saved to/restored from `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: well the function works fine in api 21 or 22, don't need reflection, the updated question is how to access next alarm on older api's. Saving the alarms in a database is not the solution for me, i'm trying to make a locker and i need to display the next alarm on the screen. Seeing that the Go Locker shows it, there is a solution somehow, but unfortunatly for me, i need to search more

Comment: I meant that if you have access to the source, you may find a way to get that information from internals not exposed via the API (and this is where reflection could be used). But that assumes that you know what is behind the API.

Answer (score 0):

Oki, so i can use the alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock() for API 21 and 22, and for older i found this: [android - get time of the next alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600378/android-get-time-of-the-next-alarm) works fine on multiple devices.